# Getting complete value from ElasticSearch query

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, plainelastic.net

I have the following structure on my ElasticSearch:

```
{
    _index: 3_exposureindex
    _type: exposuresearch
    _id: 12738
    _version: 4
    _score: 1
    _source: {
        Name: test2_update
        Description:
        CreateUserId: 8
        SourceId: null
        Id: 12738
        ExposureId: 12738
        CreateDate: 2014-06-20T16:18:50.500
        UpdateDate: 2014-06-20T16:19:57.547
        UpdateUserId: 8
    }
    fields: {
        _parent: 1
    }
}
```

I am trying to get both, the data in `_source` as well as that in `fields`, when I run the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "Id": [
        "12738"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

All I get are the values contained in `_source`, whereas, if I run the query:

```
{
  "fields": [
    "_parent"
  ],
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "Id": [
        "12738"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then I only the `fields`. Is there a way to get both? I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud be able to  specify "_source" in the "fields"

Example:

```
{
  "fields": [
    "_parent",
    "_source"
  ],
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "Id": [
        "12738"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Egad, it was this simple! I feel ashamed of even asking this question :)